# Cafe latte with 0% fat milk?

Tags: latte

Is it possible to order cafe latte with 0% fat milk? Or most places would say that is not latte etc
Would the taste be bad?

Comment: Just checking: You mean "milk with 0% fat", not "0% milk", right? Cafe Latte with 0% milk is simply espresso.

Comment: @DCTLib:Yes non-fat milk (skimmed or 0% fat)

Answer (score 3):

Cafe Latte comes in many variants, all of which are Cafe Lattes. If you ever see anyone ordering a "Cafe Latte with nonfat milk" at Starbucks, this typically refers to a Cafe Latte with milk that has less than 0.5% of fat.

Note that 0.0% fat milk is not available everywhere. For example, it is common in central Europe that the lowest percentage of fat available for milk is 0.3% or 1.5%. I recently checked at a German Starbucks what milk they have to pour into filter coffee, and they start at 1.5% fat. Note that even if the label on a box of milk says 0% fat, there will always be some traces of fat.

Whether it tastes well: that is subjective. Fat *does* add to the taste. But a 0.3% fat milk Cafe Latte is probably closer to a 1.5% fat milk Cafe Latte in terms of taste than to a coconut milk Cafe Latte, which is also enjoyed by many coffee consumers and also bears the name "Cafe Latte". Whether you will actually be able to get a close-to-0% fat Cafe Latte depends on the place that you are visiting: not all coffee places may have that type of milk in stock.

Comment: If it is <1% that is fine. I wasn't sure if an order of latte with low fat milk would be accepted or considered that it is not a latte

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that it is still a Latte.  Given that a Latte has espresso, steamed milk and foam components, a 0% skim milk latte will have all of those components.

Indeed, some of the most resilient foams are made with low fat milk, as the protein structure is not interfered with by the fat.  You tend to get very smooth and densely structured foams.  I know because those are the Latte's I make for some people.

In fact, [Harold McGee](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-froth-milk-for-cappuccinos-in-the-microwave-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-100716) has a recipe for making foamed milk with a cocktail shaker and a microwave, which depends upon low fat milk to work.